# Can the diagonalizing matrix be to the left of the matrix of interest?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I've always diagonalized matrices in this way

$$S^{-1}AS = D$$

where $D$ diagonal and the columns of $S$ are the (linearly independent) eigenvectors of $A$.

Could I instead do $SAS^{-1}$?  Is there an obvious flaw to this multiplication?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $S$ of one approach is the $S^{-1}$ of the other.